# Unable to use flags in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, flags

I'm unable to use flags in OpenCV.

For example:

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('k.jpg',cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.namedWindow('Pic',cv2.CV_WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow('Pic', image)

cv2.waitKey()
```

In this program I'm able to use `cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` but I'm not able to use flags for `namedWindow` here. This one gives error:

```
module has no attribute CV_WINDOW_NORMAL
```

Comment: It is `cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_NORMAL`

Answer (score 4):

Just a short update:

Since OpenCV 3.0, these are cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE and cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL (use help(cv2) for the whole list).