# Loading own dataset like MNIST images

Tags: python, opencv, mnist

I am trying to load my own hand written images and test them in my MNIST model. But, i need to pre process the images first. I have 100 images, 10 of every 10 digits saved on the folder images. I am getting error and i don't know if this code works. Any help?

```
import cv2
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy import ndimage
import math
def loadImages(path):

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        gray = cv2.imread("image", cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
        gray = cv2.resize(255-gray, (28, 28))
        (thresh, gray) = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        while np.sum(gray[0]) == 0:
            gray = gray[1:]
        while np.sum(gray[:,0]) == 0:
            gray = np.delete(gray,0,1)
        while np.sum(gray[-1]) == 0:
            gray = gray[:-1]
        while np.sum(gray[:,-1]) == 0:
            gray = np.delete(gray,-1,1)
        rows,cols = gray.shape
        if rows > cols:
            factor = 20.0/rows
            rows = 20
            cols = int(round(cols*factor))
            gray = cv2.resize(gray, (cols,rows))
        else:
            factor = 20.0/cols
            cols = 20
            rows = int(round(rows*factor))
            gray = cv2.resize(gray, (cols, rows))
        colsPadding = (int(math.ceil((28-cols)/2.0)),int(math.floor((28-cols)/2.0)))
        rowsPadding = (int(math.ceil((28-rows)/2.0)),int(math.floor((28-rows)/2.0)))
        gray = np.lib.pad(gray,(rowsPadding,colsPadding),'constant')
        shiftx,shifty = getBestShift(gray)
        shifted = shift(gray,shiftx,shifty)
        gray = shifted
        loadedImages.append(gray)
    return loadedImages

def getBestShift(img):
    cy,cx = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(img)
    rows,cols = img.shape
    shiftx = np.round(cols/2.0-cx).astype(int)
    shifty = np.round(rows/2.0-cy).astype(int)
    return shiftx,shifty
path = 'images/'

def shift(img,sx,sy):
    rows,cols = img.shape
    M = np.float32([[1,0,sx],[0,1,sy]])
    shifted = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))
    return shifted
imgs = loadImages(path)
rgb=np.array(imgs)
```

Error:AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to use flags in opencv Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696251/unable-to-use-flags-in-opencv-python)

Answer (score 0):

According to this link

[Read image grayscale opencv 3.0.0-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339315/read-image-grayscale-opencv-3-0-0-dev)

So, you need to run this script in python 2.4 (I guess) or change flag names according to your current python version